# Stop Excel mouse cursor from flickering over button

Tags: excel, user-interface

When I create a button with a macro attached to it, and hover the mouse cursor over the button, it flickers between the default pointing hand cursor and what looks like an all-white pointing hand that's 1 pixel further left.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem and it is really annoying

Comment: @MZimmerman6, I'm afraid I never did find a solution.

Comment: darn, alright thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem (if not the same problem).

1. When not moving the mouse, but hovering over a button, the hand appears to flicker.
2. When moving the mouse, and passing over a button, the hand flickers and the cursor slows down.

Referencing Scoox' solution, I placed the code in a function to fire when the workbook opens.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow
End Sub
```

This eliminated the stationary mouse flickering and the lag in the pointer movement over the button.  However, if you move slowly over the button, there still some slight flickering.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code before the code that causes the mouse pointer to flash the hourglass.

```
Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow 'Stops mouse pointer flashing hourglass
```

That should stop the flashing.

Comment: The mouse pointer is flashing when I simply hover over the button, before any macro code is actually running.